# I am having problem with this question including topics of polynomials and differentiation.

Tags: polynomials

How many roots of the equation $3x^4 + 6x^3 + x^2 + 6x +3$ are real?

My first instinct was to assume this is f(x). Now, $f '(x) = 12x^3 + 18x^2 + 2x + 6$. Again, $f ''(x)$ would be $18x^2 + 18x + 1$, now this clearly has two factors, so $f ' (x)$ has two turning points, ie. it has three roots. so $f(x)$ has three turning points, ie. it has 4 roots. But the answer is supposed to be 2. I don't have much knowledge of calculus. Please help, appreciate it.

Edit: I know this can be solved in a bunch of different methods but i just want to know the basic differentiation one because i want to learn that concept as it would help me later on in this chapter. Thanks to everyone.

Comment: Sketch the graph. You get more information that way than by following rules and formulas. Even before you do, you should be able to imagine a fourth degree polynomial with three turning points that has just two roots. PS Write mathematics here using mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @EthanBolker I did, but the graph has only one turning point which led me to believe I must have made a mistake and as I don't know much of calculus, I couldn't find it. I tried it a lot of times. Could you please help?

Answer (score 1):

We could extract the existence of roots by using Intermediate Value Theorem. Our function is $x^4$ dominated when $|x|>6$ so there are no roots in $(-\infty,-6]$ since the function is always positive there. Also the function is positive when $x\geq 0$ so a quick inspection on the interval $(-6,0)$ will be sufficient to determine how many real roots the function has.

Investigating the $f'(x)$ on that interval might give us an insight how to bisect the interval also.

Answer (score 0):

The symmetry in the coefficients should make you think of writing the polynomial in terms of $x+\frac 1x$.  Your polynomial is  $f(x)=x^2\left(3(x+\frac 1x)^2+6(x+\frac 1x)-5\right)$.  There is no root at $x=0$, so all roots come from the right term, which is just a quadratic.  One of the two roots of the quadratic is less than $2$ in absolute value, which corresponds to complex values of $x$, so there are only two real roots coming from $x+\frac 1x=-1-2\sqrt{\frac 23}$

Comment: I am actually managed to solve it using this method but i really wanted to solve it using differentiation because that would give me some insights on how to make the graph. Anyways, Thank you for your time